# How do I count repetitive/continuous appearance of a character in String(When I don't know index of start/end)?

Tags: java, string

So if I have 22332, I want to replace that for BEA, as in mobile keypad.I want to see how many times a digit appear so that I can count A--2,B--22,C--222,D--3,E--33,F--333, etc(and a 0 is pause).I want to write a decoder that takes in digit string and replaces digit occurrences with letters.example : 44335557075557777 will be decoded as HELP PLS.

This is the key portion of the code:

```
public void printMessages() throws Exception {
 File msgFile = new File("messages.txt");

 Scanner input = new Scanner(msgFile);

while(input.hasNext()) {
  String x = input.next();
  String y = input.nextLine();
  System.out.println(x+":"+y);
}
```

It takes the input from a file as digit String.Then Scanner prints the digit.I tried to split the string digits and then I don't know how to evaluate the appearance of the mentioned kind in the question.

```
  for(String x : b.split(""))
       System.out.print(x);
gives: 44335557075557777(input from the file).
```

I don't know how can I call each repetitive index and see how they formulate such pattern as in mobile keypad.If I use for loop then I have to cycle through whole string and use lots of if statements. There must be some other way.

Comment: What code have you tried? Also, you could help by explaining your logic. How do you know that 22 is B and not AA?

Comment: Post the code you have written. StackOverflow does not provide coding service.

Comment: How do you recognise that 22 is B and not AA? Your input should probably contain some pause symbols like `,` or `-` or whatever you pick.

Comment: Yes my input also has symbol for pause.I'm updating with my code soon.@bm/Ceelos

Comment: @JecobSolomon what does your `File messages.txt` contain?

Comment: 6107586533: 44335557075557777
4848675309: 53366 6699044404666804448
6107584096: 94466602777330999666887770223377778077778 883 336687777 (String of digit, I will decode it using a decoder method)

Comment: Does `22233` spell **`ABE`**, `BAE`, `CE`, `AAAE`, `ABDD`, `BADD`, `CDD`, or `AAADD`?

Comment: 22233 spell CE @ Andreas.It is as in mobile keypad.Pressing one time 1 is A,double pressing is B, Three times pressing is C and so on.

Comment: Why not `ABE`? Should we assume that original message like `AB` or `BA` is impossible? If yes then that information is very important and should be part of your question.

Comment: It denotes repetitive occurrence as in pressing mobile keypad and I don't know how to approach.I have limited skill with Strings.I am a beginner.When you take a mobile phone that does not have letter keypad, you have to press 1 three times to get C, 1 two times to get B and 1 one time to get an A.0 denotes pause then 202233 will be ABE @Pshemo

Comment: Oh, I just read your edit to previous comment. So `0` is pause. Then OK your question is a lot clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another suggestion of making use of regex in breaking the encoded string.

By making use of look-around + back-reference makes it easy to split the string at positions that preceding and following characters are different.

e.g.

```
String line = "44335557075557777";
String[] tokens = line.split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)");
// tokens will contain ["44", "33", "555", "7", "0", "7", "555", "7777"]
```

Then it should be trivial for you to map each string to its corresponding character, either by a `Map` or even naively by bunch of `if-else`s

---

Edit: Some background on the regex

```
(?<=(.))(?!\1)

(?<=   )         : Look behind group, which means finding 
                   something (a zero-length patternin this example)
                   preceded by this group of pattern
    ( )          : capture group #1
     .           : any char
                 : zero-length pattern between look behind and look
                   ahead group
       (?!  )    : Negative look ahead group, which means finding
                   a pattern (zero-length in this example) NOT followed
                   by this group of pattern
          \1     : back-reference, whatever matched by 
                   capture group #1
```

So it means, find any zero-length positions, for which the character before and after such position is different, and use such positions to do splitting.

Comment: that's so simple!Thank you!But can you please explain how "(?<=(.))(?!\\1)" this works?

Comment: @JecobSolomon Though this solution works, for the sake of your own learning experience, it will be better if you can implement a util function giving similar result, by making use of loops and `String.charAt(pos)` etc, so you can manually break the string into pieces by yourself.